# Checking whether an ObjC property is nullable at runtime

Tags: objective-c, nullable, introspection, declared-property

I'm trying to figure out at runtime whether a property of a class is nullable. For example:

```
@interface A : NSObject

+ (NSSet<NSString *> *)nullableProperties;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *description;

@property (readonly, nonatomic, nullable) NSError *error;

@end

@implementation A

+ (NSSet<NSString *> *)nullableProperties {
  // Code that identifies nullable properties.
}

@end
```

`nullableProperties` should in this case return an `NSSet` with `@"error"`.

`property_getAttributes` function can provide information of some of the attributes (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html)). Unfortunately, it doesn't provide information on whether the property is declared as nullable.

I would like to avoid implementing `nullableProperties` for every class that I need to know the nullable properties for.

Comment: The `nullable` modifier is simply information to the compiler that helps it provide an appropriate interface to Swift; It doesn't modify the compiled code.

Comment: As far I know you can't get declared variable value with `class`(+) function. Check your code if anything wrong.

Comment: Pre-compile script to scrape the property info and insert the method decl? libclang is pretty easy to use, although I've no idea if it exposes this attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every Objective-C pointer or object property is technically nullable at runtime. The nullability specifiers are simply compiler hints that don't affect the actual built binary [edit: by which I mean, since this is apparently unclear, the 1s and 0s that get written to the disk in either Mach-O or some other comparable binary format by the compiler and linker, and which contain the machine instructions that represent the program logic along with other information and metadata]. Therefore, there's no way to detect at runtime which properties are nullable and which are not.

Comment: +1 Completely correct except of the *therefore*. Sometimes you can get type information at runtime that is not important for the runtime environment's work itself.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad Not nullability. That information is not present at runtime.

Comment: I know that. But you said, that is not available, *because* (therefore) it is solely a compiler hint. But this is not a valid argument.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad Something that is solely a compiler hint that does not affect the compiled binary is, by definition, something that you cannot detect at runtime.

Comment: That's not correct, because the RTTI can be and is richer than solely the necessary information. For example passing a pointer (to a C object) to a method, the type of the pointee does not effect the executable. However, you can ask for that type. Your conclusion, that what is not necessary is not there, is not correct.

Comment: The C types of arguments to methods actually *are* stored in the binary; you can see this for yourself if you look at the declaration for `struct objc_method_declaration` in `/usr/include/objc/runtime.h`; the struct contains a `char *` member which stores a string representation of the C types of the arguments to the method (as well as the return type). This is how Objective-C is able to access this information at runtime. By contrast, the Objective-C types of object pointer arguments cannot be deduced, because those, like nullability, exist only in the source, being just `id` in the binary.

Comment: I know that. This is, why your "therefore" is wrong as I said in my very first comment. "Objctive-C" (wrong term, Objective-C is a language, likely you meant the RTE) does not need to know, what type a C pointer refers to. BTW: The property type string contains information not used by the RTE itself, too.

Comment: You claimed that the type of a C pointer in a method signature does not affect the executable; this is untrue. If you peek inside the binary with a hex editor, you will find the type encodings of all your Objective-C methods are stored in there. Thus, changing the type does change the binary. By contrast, nullability specifiers do not affect how the binary is built at all. To be able to get this information at runtime, it has to be written down somewhere. Unfortunately the Psychic Friends Network cannot be used because its UI is still telephone-only and Macs don't ship with modems anymore.

Comment: I know, that they are stored there. *This is, what I said.* But it is not needed for the execution of the code. *This is, what I said.* So, there is an information that has no meaning to the program flow. So, your conclusion in your answer is wrong. I *really,* do not know, how to give you further explanations. I'm repeating me. I do not think, that a further discussion is useful.

Comment: And if "not needed for the execution of the code" were what I said, then that would be relevant. But it wasn't, and it's not. What I said was, "the nullability specifiers are simply compiler hints that don't affect the actual built binary." And this is true. Changing the C type of an argument to a method *will in fact change the binary*, since different type information will be written into it. Changing a nullability specifier will not. If you compile down to the same exact binary, that code has to behave the same way at runtime. I don't know how much clearer I can get than that.